# How to update a field value by default in mysql in single query

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I have a table in mysql that contains price field (around 500 rows in that table). Now i wan to update the price field in such a manner that i can set 5 in all those where currently thr is no data. Although around 100-120 rows[price] contains some values that i want to remain as it is. I tried setting 5 as default through phpmyadmin but it wont work. I don't want to insert manually these 350-400 data fields. using phymyadmin as a tool.

Comment: "No data" means there is `NULL` in those rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the base case of the [UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html) query.

```
UPDATE table
SET price = 5
WHERE price = 0
```

In the future I strongly recommend you to start using NULL as the empty value, because you may very well have times where `0` is *not* considered "empty".